# State reactjs - when I click to set the value, I set all

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx

I have a list of tickets and, in the tickets, I created a button for the user to inform the number of tickets he wants to buy. However, when he adds in a ticket, he ends up adding everyone.

The backend sends a list of tickets, and I map the list to render on the front end.

[image]

Code:

```
export default function Events() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const { data: tickets } = useSWR(`/v1/events/${slug}/tickets`, fetch);

  if (!tickets) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Loading />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <CardTickets>
        <TitleTicket>
          <span>Ingressos</span>
        </TitleTicket>
        {tickets.map(ticket => (
          <ContentTicket>
            <h1>{ticket.name}</h1>
            <span>{ticket.description}</span>
            <PositionButton>
              <h1 className="valueTicket">R${ticket.price}</h1>
              <ButtonTicket>
                <button
                  className="buttonLess"
                  onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}
                >
                  -
                </button>
                <button className="value">{count}</button>
                <button
                  className="buttonMore"
                  onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}
                >
                  {" "}
                  +{" "}
                </button>
              </ButtonTicket>
            </PositionButton>
            <DetailLeft />
            <DetailRight />
          </ContentTicket>
        ))}
      </CardTickets>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: IMO your code looks good, can you provide us more code to check, for example parent?

Comment: I added the entire component

Answer (score -1):

As I thought, you are using just one state for all the tickets, thats why

[image]

You should create component for ticket and has **useState** there , so every ticket will has its own state

for example make this your **new component** and pass ticket **as prop** and move **useState** ni there

```
<ContentTicket>
            <h1>{ticket.name}</h1>
            <span>{ticket.description}</span>
            <PositionButton>
              <h1 className="valueTicket">R${ticket.price}</h1>
              <ButtonTicket>
                <button
                  className="buttonLess"
                  onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}
                >
                  -
                </button>
                <button className="value">{count}</button>
                <button
                  className="buttonMore"
                  onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}
                >
                  {" "}
                  +{" "}
                </button>
              </ButtonTicket>
            </PositionButton>
            <DetailLeft />
            <DetailRight />
          </ContentTicket>
```